# Является ли функция интерфейса ActionListener - actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) объектом-богом?

Tags: java, swing

Только изучаю Java и столкнулся с такой вещью что все повально для кнопок пишут

```
button.addActionListener( new ActionListenerImplementation())
```

И такой вопрос - если у меня на форме 10 кнопок, каждая из которых выполняет свое действие, то мне в классе `ActionListenerImplementation` в функции `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`   надо писать 10 раз

```
Если Источник = кнопка 1 Тогда Делай_1 

ИначеЕсли Источник = кнопка 2 Тогда ДелайДругое

ИначеЕсли.....
```

Подскажите, как решается такая ситуация?

Comment: Может в таких случаях просто прописываются лямбда функции\анонимные классы?

Comment: А откуда пришла идея писать общий класс-реализацию для действий _всех_ кнопок, чтобы потом определять источник действия?

Comment: А всё от неопытности. Норм более менее больших проектов, в которых можно подсмотреть как правильно строить архитектуру проекта я не нашел пока, а закрепить знания и покодить охота.


Пока только начал, поэтому все пишу в одно. Как увижу, что пора разносить по разным классам - буду разносить.

Но вот пример. Есть форма, на ней кнопки - открыть калькулятор, открыть сайт, запустить игру и т д. .. думаю под мой вопрос подходит

Comment: Раньше плодили многословные анонимные классы _для каждой кнопки_ в виде: `btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){@Override public void actionPerformet(ActionEvent ae) {btn1Clicked();}});`, где `btn1handler` - реализация действия на конкретной кнопке в классе формы.  При помощи лямбд запись сокращается до: `btn1.addActionListener(ae -> btn1Clicked());`

Comment: я вот щас в процессе кода  тож до этого дошел, что надо функции свои прописывать, а в лямбде их просто вызывать. Отлично, что догадка потвердилась, спасибо)

Comment: [Божественный объект - антипаттерн](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)